# How to apply chain rule to a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

There is a simple differential equation
$ y''(x) + (\varepsilon - x^2) y(x) = 0 $. If one uses the new variable $ x^2 = s $, using the chain rule, this differential equation becomes $ 4 s y''(s) + 2 y'(s) + (\varepsilon - s) y(s) = 0 $. Now, I want to do it in Mathematica. I define the differential equatrion as

```
diff[x_] := y''[x] + (ε - x^2) y[x];

Simplify[diff[x] /. x^2 -> s]
```

But, it does not work. How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
deq = y''[x] + (epsilon - x^2) y[x];

deq /. {y -> (y[#^2] &)} /. x -> Sqrt[s]
(*(epsilon - s) y[s] + 4 s y''[s] + 2 y'[s]*)
```

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to use the package [`MoreCalculus`](https://github.com/kubaPod/MoreCalculus) by Kuba

```
<< MoreCalculus`
diff[x_] := y''[x] + (epsilon - x^2) y[x] == 0;
DChange[diff[x], {x^2 == s}, {x}, {s}, y[x]]
```

$$
\epsilon  y(s)+4 s y''(s)+2 y'(s)=s y(s)
$$

Comment: Worth mentioning that `DChange` is the _only_ function contained in that package at the moment.